# Fazendo busca no ListView usando o EditText e Cursor

Tags: android, listview, algoritmo-de-busca, edittext, cursor

Bom dia pessoal, eu precisaria tirar uma dúvida. Estou com uma aplicação aonde possuo um `ListView` que puxa as informações do banco de dados, e gostaria de fazer um campo de busca no qual eu estou utilizando um `EditText`, que está acima desse `ListView`, estou tentando filtrar as informações do `ListView` pela descrição do produto e gostaria que quando colocasse no `EditText` ele trouxesse as informações do produto, porém não estou conseguindo. Alguém conhece alguma forma de fazer isso utilizando o `Cursor` e `Adapter`? Já vi em diversos lugares, mas ainda não funcionou.

Código de Listar os produtos no ListView:

```
public void lprod(SQLiteDatabase db){


        ArrayList<modelListprod> prod = new ArrayList<modelListprod>();
        //Passa para dentro do while
        //listprod = new modelListprod();
        String descricao = "";
        String ean = "";
        String status = "";
        Double precoprod;
        String categoria;
        int codigo;
        final SQLiteDatabase d5 = dadosOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String rawQuery = "SELECT produto.descricao, produto.ean, produto.status, produto.precoprod, categoria.descricao, produto.cod FROM produto  INNER JOIN categoria  ON categoria.id  = produto.codigocateg";
        Cursor cursor5 = d5.rawQuery(
                rawQuery,
                null
        );
        if (cursor5 != null) {
            itensprod.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (cursor5.moveToFirst()) {

                do {

                    //uma nova instância por cada registo
                    listprod = new modelListprod();

                    descricao = cursor5.getString(0);
                    ean = cursor5.getString(1);
                    status = cursor5.getString(2);
                    precoprod = cursor5.getDouble(3);
                    categoria = cursor5.getString(4);
                    codigo = cursor5.getInt(5);
                    listprod.setDescricao(descricao);
                    listprod.setCategoria(categoria);
                    listprod.setEan(ean);
                    listprod.setPreco(precoprod);
                    listprod.setStatus(status);
                    listprod.setCod(codigo);

                    //Adiciona ao array


                    listadeprod.add(listprod);


                    itensprod.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } while (cursor5.moveToNext());
            }


        }
        //
        //Passa para dentro do while
        //listadeprod.add(listprod);
        AdapterProd adapterProd = new AdapterProd(this, listadeprod);
        listproduto.setAdapter(adapterProd);
    }
```

Adaptador do ListView:

```
class AdapterProd extends ArrayAdapter<modelListprod> implements Filterable {

    MainActivity c = new MainActivity();

    private Context context;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    CustomFilter filter;
    private ArrayList<modelListprod> list;;
    private ArrayList<modelListprod> lista = null;
    private int valida = 1;

    public AdapterProd(Context context, ArrayList<modelListprod> listap){
        super(context, 0, listap);

        this.list = listap;
        this.context = context;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.lista = listap;
        //this.lista.addAll(listap);
    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        TextView descricao;
        TextView categoria;
        TextView preco;
        TextView ean;
        TextView status;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public modelListprod getItem(int position){
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position){
        return list.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertVieww, ViewGroup parent) {
       final ViewHolder holder;
       if (convertVieww == null){
           holder = new ViewHolder();
           convertVieww = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_prod, null);
           holder.descricao = (TextView)convertVieww.findViewById(R.id.tvdescricao2);
           holder.categoria = (TextView)convertVieww.findViewById(R.id.tvcategoria2);
           holder.preco = (TextView)convertVieww.findViewById(R.id.tvpreco2);
           holder.ean = (TextView)convertVieww.findViewById(R.id.tvean2);
           holder.status = (TextView)convertVieww.findViewById(R.id.tvstatus2);
           convertVieww.setTag(holder);
       }else{
           holder = (ViewHolder)convertVieww.getTag();
       }
       holder.descricao.setText(list.get(position).getDescricao());
       holder.categoria.setText(list.get(position).getCategoria());
       holder.preco.setText(list.get(position).getPreco().toString());
       holder.ean.setText(list.get(position).getEan());
       holder.status.setText(list.get(position).getStatus());

       return convertVieww;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter(){
        if (filter == null){
            filter= new CustomFilter();
        }
        return filter;
    }

    class CustomFilter extends Filter{

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if(constraint != null && constraint.length()>0){
                constraint=constraint.toString().toUpperCase();

                ArrayList<modelListprod> filters = new ArrayList<modelListprod>();

                for (int i=0; i<lista.size(); i++){
                    if (lista.get(i).getDescricao().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)){
                        modelListprod modelListprod = new modelListprod(lista.get(i).getDescricao());
                        filters.add(modelListprod);
                    }
                }
                results.count=filters.size();
                results.values=filters;
            }else{
               results.count=lista.size();
               results.values=lista;
            }

            return  results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                list=(ArrayList<modelListprod>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Model do ListView:

```
public class modelListprod implements Serializable {
    int cod;
    String descricao;
    String categoria;
    Double Preco;
    String ean;
    String status;

    public modelListprod(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public modelListprod() {

    }

    public int getCod() {
        return cod;
    }

    public void setCod(int cod) {
        this.cod = cod;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public String getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }

    public void setCategoria(String categoria) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }

    public Double getPreco() {
        return Preco;
    }

    public void setPreco(Double preco) {
        Preco = preco;
    }

    public String getEan() {
        return ean;
    }

    public void setEan(String ean) {
        this.ean = ean;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma dica de como devo implementar o filtro que está no `Adaptador` na classe que chama o `ListView` ?

Comment: Onde está seu EditText? e qual o problema que tá dando desse jeito que está ai?

Comment: O EditText está declarado no topo da minha Main Activity, no caso eu não estou sabendo usar ele para filtrar as informações do listview. Tentei de algumas maneiras mas não funcionou.

Comment: Se puder edite a pergunta e acrescente o que você tentou fazer no EditText.

Comment: Eu consegui solucionar o problema agora, irei acrescentar aqui o código funcionando. Obrigado pela participação do post.

Comment: Blz, desculpa pedir a parte do EditText, mas era necessário pra melhor entendimento.

Comment: Magina Murilo, agradeço a participação, eu realmente esqueci de coloca-lo no inicio, mas obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 1):

Foi possível solucionar o problema, no caso precisa estar acrescentando junto a esse código mais algumas linhas, veja abaixo:

```
public void lprodfiltra (SQLiteDatabase db){
        ArrayList<modelListprod> prod = new ArrayList<modelListprod>();
        //Passa para dentro do while
        //listprod = new modelListprod();
        String descricao = "";
        String ean = "";
        String status = "";
        Double precoprod;
        String categoria;
        int codigo;
        String texto;
        texto = barraproduto.getText().toString();
        final SQLiteDatabase d5 = dadosOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String rawQuery = "SELECT produto.descricao, produto.ean, produto.status, produto.precoprod, categoria.descricao, produto.cod FROM produto  " +
                "INNER JOIN categoria  ON categoria.id  = produto.codigocateg WHERE produto.descricao = '" + texto + "'";
        Cursor cursor5 = d5.rawQuery(
                rawQuery,
                null
        );
        if (cursor5 != null) {
            if (cursor5.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    //uma nova instância por cada registo
                    listprodd = new modelListprod();
                    descricao = cursor5.getString(0);
                    ean = cursor5.getString(1);
                    status = cursor5.getString(2);
                    precoprod = cursor5.getDouble(3);
                    categoria = cursor5.getString(4);
                    codigo = cursor5.getInt(5);
                    listprodd.setDescricao(descricao);
                    listprodd.setCategoria(categoria);
                    listprodd.setEan(ean);
                    listprodd.setPreco(precoprod);
                    listprodd.setStatus(status);
                    listprodd.setCod(codigo);
                    //Adiciona ao array
                    listadeprodd.add(listprodd);
                } while (cursor5.moveToNext());
            }
            listproduto.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    modelListprod c = (modelListprod) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlteraProd.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Dados", (Serializable) c);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
        //
        //Passa para dentro do while
        //listadeprod.add(listprod);
        AdapterProd adapterProd = new AdapterProd(this, listadeprodd);
        listproduto.setAdapter(adapterProd);
    }

    public void filtrando(View view){
        String texto2;
        texto2 = barraproduto.getText().toString();
        if (texto2 != "") {
            lprodfiltra(conexao);
            itensprod.clear();
        }

    }
```

depois de acrescentar as linhas, basta colocar o evento "filtrando" no onClick de um botão.